# Hiding/showing paragraphs according to checkbox's checked status and input text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

There are 4 paragraphs, a blank text field, 1 checkbox and a button.

I want 1 paragraph to hide when I check the checkbox and write "1" in the field, 2 paragraphs to hide when I check the checkbox and write down 2, etc.

The HTML:

```
<p class="p1">P1</p>
<p class="p2">P2</p>
<p class="p3">P3</p>
<p class="p4">P4</p>

<input id="txt" type="text" name="fld" value="" /> <br /> <br />

P <input id="pcheck" type="checkbox" name="pcheckbox" /> <br /> <br />

<input id="disapp" type="button" value="Disappear" />
```

The JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#disapp").click(function() {
        if(($("#pcheck").is(":checked")) && ($(#txt).val()=="1") {
            $(".p1").hide();    
        }
    });
});
```

I tried formatting it also like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(disapp).click(function() {
        if(($pcheck.checked) && ($txt.value()=="1")) {
            $p1.hide();     
        }
    });
});
```

And I don't know which formatting is more correct and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You must be getting syntax error see [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some syntax problems, which causes errors. You can use the developer console in your browser to see the errors.

What's wrong with your first script block:

`$(#txt).val()` doesn't work because a selector needs to be a string. Change it to `$('#txt').val()`.

Also your `if` statement misses a closing parentheses. It should be `if(($("#pcheck").is(":checked")) && ($(#txt).val()=="1"))`

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/75wjrbyj/

Your second script block makes the same selector error multiple times, as long as you don't define the variables `disapp`, `$pcheck` etc. it will throw errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, so here my omission is. I must be more attentive. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Create selector using the text field value and toggle visibility using **[`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** method with a Boolean parameter in this case **[`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** method returns Boolean value and it can be used.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#disapp").click(function() {
    $(".p" + $('#txt').val().trim()).toggle(!$("#pcheck").is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="p1">P1</p>
<p class="p2">P2</p>
<p class="p3">P3</p>
<p class="p4">P4</p>

<input id="txt" type="text" name="fld" value="" />
<br />
<br />P
<input id="pcheck" type="checkbox" name="pcheckbox" />
<br />
<br />

<input id="disapp" type="button" value="Disappear" />
```

---

Your code have various bugs:  In first case there is missing quotes around the text box selector and one additional parenthesis also. Change it like `if($("#pcheck").is(":checked") && $("#txt").val()=="1")`. In second case all the variables are undefined, I couldn't see anywhere it as defined.

Comment: Thank you so much, but for now it sounds too complicated for me(( And yes, I also thought that the second case was completely wrong, but somewhere saw an example and thought maybe it will work. Thanks again.

Comment: @tomalvi : anyway glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#disapp").click(function() {
        if(($("#pcheck").is(":checked"))){
if($("#txt").val()=="1")
            $(".p1").hide();
    if($("#txt").val()=="2")
            $(".p2").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the required behaviour by using the `index` of the `p` elements and `slice()`. Try this:

```js
$('#disapp').click(function() {
  var index = parseInt($('#txt').val(), 10);
  var $p = $('p');

  if (!index) {
    $p.show();
  } else if ($('#pcheck').is(':checked')) {
    $p.show().slice(0, index).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>P1</p>
<p>P2</p>
<p>P3</p>
<p>P4</p>

<input id="txt" type="text" name="fld" value="" /><br /><br />
P<input id="pcheck" type="checkbox" name="pcheckbox" /><br /><br />
<input id="disapp" type="button" value="Disappear" />
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this after some time!

Answer (score 0):

I think **switch case** is more better to handle in this case ...

```
$("#disapp").click(function() {
        var p = $("#txt").val();
        if($("#pcheck").is(":checked")) {
            switch(p) {
            case "1" :  $(".p1").hide();    
            case "2" :  $(".p2").hide();
            case "3" :  $(".p3").hide();
            case "4" :  $(".p4").hide();
            default :  
        }
        }
    });
```

or

```
$("#disapp").click(function() {
        var p = $("#txt").val();
        if($("#pcheck").is(":checked")) {           
            $(".p"+p).hide();
        }        
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a beginner and unfortunately not familiar with switch case yet. Anyways, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that i put together. it does modify parts of your body and totally rewritten the script. but it does what you described in your description.

```
<script language=JavaScript>

var NumberOfPs=4;


var allPars= new Array(NumberOfPs-1)
self.window.onload=LoadAll









function LoadAll(){
  var i;

  for (i=0;i<NumberOfPs;i++)
  {


    allPars[i]=document.getElementById ("par" + (i+1)).innerHTML;


  }
}






function disappear(){

  var x=document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var i

  x=Math.floor (x);


  if (document.getElementById("pcheck").checked)
  {



    for (i=1;i<=NumberOfPs;i++)
    {


      if (i<=x)
        document.getElementById ("par"+i).innerHTML="";
      else
        document.getElementById ("par"+i).innerHTML=allPars[i-1];



    }





  }



}



</script>

<body bgcolor="white">



  <span id=Par1>
    <p class="p1">P1</p>
  </span>

  <span id=Par2>
    <p class="p2">P2</p>
  </span>


  <span id=Par3>
    <p class="p3">P3</p>
  </span>


  <span id=Par4>
    <p class="p4">P4</p>
  </span>




  <input id="txt" type="text" name="fld" value="" /> <br /> <br />

  P <input id="pcheck" type="checkbox" name="pcheckbox" /> <br /> <br />

  <input id="disapp" type="button" value="Disappear" onclick=disappear() />


</body>
```

notice that i moved the P tags in individual Span tags.

If you add more p tags you can change the `var NumberOfPs=4` to `var NumberOfPs=x` where **x** is the amount of p tags you have.

*ps: If you decrease the number you write in the textbox and click disappear, then the p's that are greater than the current number will Reappear.*

Comment: Oh, great, the code is much shorter now. I'm a beginner, but when I get acquainted to web-programming more, I will surely look at this again. Thanks!